# Possible to have a function thats not a method in java?

Tags: java

In this Java program I'm writing I’m finding that I’m clogging up the `main()` method with a lot of code that would make it hard to quickly understand/read. Specifically due to a lot of error checking that I’m doing. As a result I want to write a quick function that is only going to be used by this one method to improve readability.

Is writing another method within the class my only option or are there other alternatives?

Comment: Short answer: yes. You could however make another class and write it in there.

Comment: you should at least give us an example or some hint from what you are trying to do, or least try to explain the question in a proper way

Comment: Nothing wrong about methods that are used only once. It's a good way to improve readability. If it's called from a `static` method (like main), it needs to be static too.

Comment: What is - to you - the difference between a function and a method?

Comment: @nivde92 Sorry if I was unclear, I just want error checking outside of the main. kiheru - thanks, I will probably do that and as Juned Ahsan suggested make it private as well. Mark Rotteveel - I guess the more I think about it the more they are similar. I had always viewed methods as the individual working components that make up an object. I got thrown off by main because I consider it seperate from an object

Comment: sorry if i was rude, there's never one way to do write code, (however you should always look forward for standards or better practices), you have to set the code that supplies your needs, always be careful of things like variable scopes, redundant code or rewriting something that's already done. Trying to give an answer to your question, you could also declare the method static (if you are not going to use it at any inherited class) and call it like this ClassName.methodName();

Comment: @nivde92 the question is short and concise and it is demonstrated by the 3 answers OP received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is writing another method within the class my only option or are there other alternatives?

It depends:

- If the methods should belong only to this class, they should be declared as `private` or `protected` methods in the class, depending if the class can be inherited or not.
- If the methods should be reused in other classes, it would be better to move it to utility classes as `public`. For example, check if a `String` is empty and also validating if is not `null`. Note that for this example there are methods covering these validations in utility classes from Apache Common Langs, explicitely [`StringUtils#isEmpty(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29).

By the way, Java has methods, **no** functions.

Comment: While in Java everything is called method, a *static method* is the functional equivalent to what other languages call a *function*. But java does not allow anything that resembles a *global function* (like the typical C function).

Comment: @Durandal yes, but being strict to the language, is a static method, not a function :).

Answer (score 2):

Answer is yes, generally `private` methods in the classes hold the code which is not used by outside world. But havig private methods help to reduce the cyclomatic complexity of your public methods. Smaller methods lead to more readable and understandable methods.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java was designed that way, you can only have methods. So, yes, that's the only way. Usually you would use class methods (static) for instance independent methods. These can also be within another class, for example a utility or helper class.